# Docker-Compose - Communication with "Internal" Api.

Tags: angularjs, api, nginx, docker, communication

I've developed an Angular App, that communicates with an UWSGI Flask Api throught Nginx. Currently I've 3 containers(Angular [web_admin], Api [api_admin], Nginx[nginx])

When I'm running it in my development machine, the communication is working alright. The angular requests goes through the url: http://localhost:5000 and the api response well, everything is working well.

But when I deployed it to my Production Server, I noticed that the application is not working, because the port 5000 is not opened in my firewall.

My question is kind simple, how do I make the angular container, call the api container, through internal network, instead of calling it from the external?

```
version: '2'

services:
  data:
    build: data

  neo4j:
    image: neo4j:3.0
    networks: 
      - back 
    volumes_from: 
      - data
    ports: 
      - "7474:7474"
      - "7473:7473"
      - "7687:7687"
    volumes:
      - /var/diariooficial/neo4j/data:/data  

  web_admin:
    build: frontend/web
    networks:
      - front
      - back
    ports:
      - "8001:8001"
    depends_on:
      - api_admin      
    links:
      - "api_admin:api_admin"
    volumes:
      - /var/diariooficial/upload/diario_oficial/:/var/diariooficial/upload/diario_oficial/

  api_admin:
    build: backend/api
    volumes_from: 
      - data    
    networks:
      - back   
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"   
    depends_on:
      - neo4j
      - neo4jtest
    volumes:
      - /var/diariooficial/upload/diario_oficial/:/var/diariooficial/upload/diario_oficial/

  nginx:
    build: nginx
    volumes_from: 
      - data    
    networks:
      - back
      - front
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - /var/diariooficial/log/nginx:/var/log/nginx
    depends_on:
      - api_admin      
      - web_admin

networks:
  front:
  back:
```

Answer (score 2):

Links create DNS names on the network for the services. You should have the `web_admin` service talk to `api_admin:5000` instead of `localhost:5000`. The `api_admin` DNS name will resolve to the IP address of one of the `api_admin` service.

See https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/ for an explanation, specifically:

> Each container can now look up the hostname web or db and get back the appropriate container’s IP address. For example, web’s application code could connect to the URL postgres://db:5432 and start using the Postgres database.

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for the response. I'm using the DNS name in Nginx and it works fine, but I don't know why, angular doesn't transform the dns name. 
$http.get(__env.apiUrl + '/websites')
OPTIONS http://api_admin:5000/auth/login net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED

Comment: Is this being accessed from the browser JavaScript code you mean? In that case, the request comes from outside the Docker network. You'd have to provide a way to configure the `__env.apiUrl` at runtime. It sounds like your question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/a/42938882/684908. Your URL in this case would be the IP address of the Docker host (for example, on my laptop with Docker Machine, my Docker host is 192.168.99.100).